# Superblock invalid, disk in use

Tags: server, partitioning, fsck

I have a Ubuntu Server installation on a 250Gb HDD.  During setup the drive was partitioned using LVM so my data is on /dev/sda5.  When it boots and is left idle, disk errors keep appearing just at the login prompt.

I've read that to run fsck I need to boot from the LiveCD and run the command with the drive unmounted  (and connected via a USB/SATA lead).  I have done this but the drive still seems to be mounted when I try to run fsck, for example:

```
root@ubuntu:/# fsck.ext3 -nf /dev/sdb5
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Warning! /dev/sdb5 is in use.
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext3: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext3: Bad magic number is super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 
or
e2fsck -b 32768
```

But when I run:

```
root@ubuntu:/# e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb5
```

I am told that /dev/sdb5 is in use and e2fsck cannot continue.

I have tried unmounting the drive both using the LiveCD GUI and umount command but still it won't repair the superblock.

Please can someone advise how I can resolve this?

Comment: From the Live DVD, try issuing a `swapoff -a` and then retry `fsck -f /dev/sda5`. If that doesn't work, you may have to give fsck the lvm name like /dev/ubuntu-vg/root. Use `lvmdiskscan` to see the names.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds so obvious when you say it but I had to pass the lvm name (ubuntu-vg) instead of the partition name (sda5) to fsck and it is now running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Live DVD, issue a `swapoff -a` and then retry `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`. If that doesn't work *(because sda5 is the physical volume)*, you will have to give fsck the lvm name like `/dev/ubuntu-vg/root`. Use `lvmdiskscan` to see the names.

update: `sudo fsck -f /dev/ubuntu-vg` worked.