# I cannot reboot from ubuntu, when I install ex2fsd in win10 for viewing ubuntu file from win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

1. My pc is Multiboot OS from Ubuntu 16.04 or windows10
   Boot from Ubuntu fail today. But I can boot from WIN10.
2. I install ex2fsd in WIN10, and I can see Ubuntu file system from WIN10.
   the purpose is mounting an Ubuntu file system , the I can view all the files of Ubuntu from window10
3. I also can see win10 file system from Ubuntu automatically . But I don’t install ex2fsd in Ubuntu 16.04
4. Boot from Ubuntu fail today. But I can boot from WIN10.
5. I key in “ubuntu cannot reboot after ex2fsd” in win10
   System shows : Recover Ubuntu installation after Ext2Fsd installation
   I find I can key in  e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5 in WIN10
6. C:\Program Files\Ext2Fsd>e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5
   Win10 replies
   e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
   e2fsck: Cannot allocate memory while trying to open /dev/sda5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ex2fsd` asap. It, and similar Windows drivers, corrupt the Ubuntu ext2/3/4 file system.

`fsck` the Ubuntu file system after removing this driver.

Search here on AskUbuntu for "superblock" to learn how to use backup superblocks to repair your current file system.

Examples...

[How to find superblock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033923/how-to-find-superblock)

[Journal superblock is corrupt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878840/journal-superblock-is-corrupt)

[Superblock invalid, disk in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871520/superblock-invalid-disk-in-use)

[BIOS boot partition : how to fix "Superblock invalid"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048306/bios-boot-partition-how-to-fix-superblock-invalid)