# Best filesystem for Ubuntu/Windows shared drive

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem

I have a drive intended to be shared between Ubuntu and Windows.  I've tried exFAT and NTFS and have noticed that both have high CPU load.  For example, while bringing up a couple of Vagrant instances, the mount.ntfs process uses about 90% of a core, while exFAT generally pegs one at 100%.  I've attempted and failed to get exfat-nofuse (https://github.com/dorimanx/exfat-nofuse) to install; there were make errors that appear to require development attention.  So, are there read/write filesystems that will perform well and work in both Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: Ubuntu can read and write files in NTFS, whereas Windows drivers for ext4 tend to break things. I'd use NTFS for that sharespace.

Comment: Thank you.  I've spent a bit more time on this and have found that the NTFS CPU load can be considerably reduced, unlike (so far as I can tell) exFat.  So, I'm going with that.  Tasks that completely failed previously complete in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has the [ntfs-3g](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/) package so it can read and write files in NTFS, whereas Windows drivers for ext4 [tend to break things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106734/i-cannot-reboot-from-ubuntu-when-i-install-ex2fsd-in-win10-for-viewing-ubuntu-f). I'd use NTFS for that shared space.